# What is better way to enum directories and documents

Tags: 2013, rest, folder

I need to enum directories and documents in SP 2013. I need only those the user works with (no system or web files)
To get initial lists omitting non-user ones I inquire

```
/_api/Web/Lists?$filter=BaseType+eq+1 and Hidden+eq+false and IsPrivate+eq+false and IsCatalog+eq+false
```

Than - what to do better? I have 2 options:

1. Get `/_api/Web/Lists(guid'GUID')/Items`, chose those with `FileSystemObjectType eq 0` for files and `FileSystemObjectType eq 1` for folders, and then arrange folders into tree using relative paths (e.g. for folder1="/A/B" and folder2="/A/B/C" assume that folder2 lays inside folder1)
   PS: filtering with neither
   `/_api/Web/Lists(guid'GUID')/Items?$filter=FileSystemObjectType eq
   0` nor
   `/_api/Web/Lists(guid'GUID')/Items?$filter=FileSystemObjectType+eq+0`
   does not work for me
2. Get `/_api/Web/Lists(guid'GUID')/RootFolder` and continue navigating with

`/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(FOLDER_PATH)/Folders`,
`/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(FOLDER_PATH)/Files` and
`/_api/Web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(FOLDER_PATH)`

Any other option?

2-nd is easier but I doubt if there can be some non-user files inside the folders. If not - I would prefer 2.

Thank you

Comment: Found out in question [REST with $filter for List Items in Sharepoint 2013](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/124846/rest-with-filter-for-list-items-in-sharepoint-2013)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the discussion in [REST with $filter for List Items in Sharepoint 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/124846/rest-with-filter-for-list-items-in-sharepoint-2013/124864#124864) question:

**Option 1**

Since filtering on [FileSystemObjectType property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj244796(v=office.15).aspx) does not seem to work using `$filter` query option in SharePoint 2013 REST,you could consider a another option, i.e  to filter by [FileSystemObjectType property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj244796(v=office.15).aspx) using CAML query instead as demonstrated below:

```
function getListItems(listTitle, queryViewXml)
{
   var queryPayload = { 
       'query':{ 
           '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.CamlQuery' },
           'ViewXml': queryViewXml
        } 
   }; 
   var endpointUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listTitle + "')/getitems";

   return $.ajax({
      type: "POST", 
      headers: { 
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
      }, 
      data: JSON.stringify(queryPayload),
      url: endpointUrl
   });
}

function getFolderItems(listTitle)
{
    var query = '<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="FSObjType" /><Value Type="Integer">1</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>';
    return getListItems(listTitle,query);
}
```

Usage

```
//retrieve and print folder item names
getFolderItems('Requests')
.done(function(data){
    var items = data.d.results;
    for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
          console.log(items[i].Title);   
    }
})
.fail(function(error){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error)); 
});
```

> I would prefer this option since it allows to retrieve nested
>   files/folders

**Option 2**

The limitation of this approach that it allows to return files/folders for one sub level only.

The following REST query returns top folders of `Documents` library:

```
/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Documents')/rootFolder/Folders?$expand=ListItemAllFields&$filter=ListItemAllFields ne null
```

> Filter: `ListItemAllFields ne null` is used to *exclude system folders*